# Перезапуск Activity при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня есть `Activity` в котором вопросы с вариантами, когда заканчиваются вопросы то появляется `AlertDialog` в котором находится только одна кнопка.

Можно как то реализовать перезапуск `Activity` когда нажимаешь на кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В диалоге у вас есть конструктор. Там нужно ссылку на `Activity` сохранить:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

   private Activity mActivity;

   [...]

   public CustomDialog(Activity activity) {      
     super(activity);
     // сохраняем ссылку на Activity
     mActivity = activity;
   }

   private void restartActivity() {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        // на новых версиях можно делать так
        mActivity.recreate();
     } else {
        // MyActivity - имя класса вашей Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, MyActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        // на старых приходится завершать текущую Activity 
        mActivity.finish();
        // убираем ненужную анимацию
        mActivity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

        // и запускать по-новой
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
        mActivity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
     }

   }
}
```

По нажатию на кнопку вызывайте `restartActivity`.

Comment: Это добавить в `onClick` кнопки `AlertDialog`?

Comment: Смотря откуда запускаете. Из `AlertDialog` вызвать напрямую `startActivity` нельзя, нужен контекст. `mContext.startActivity`.

Comment: А можете изменить код для `AlertDialog`?

Comment: @AkmalTilloev обновил.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую отпишусь.